# Multiplying Elements in a List

Tags: python

I want to multiply the first and second element of sum_row by 13 individually. And multiply the third and fourth by 11 individually and the last element by 9.

I guess my question really is how do I access the elements in lists, so I can use them for calculations later on?

```
matrix5x5 = [[1 for row in range (5)] for col in range (5)]
for row in matrix5x5: 
    for item in row:
        print(item,end=" ") 
    print()

sum_row = [sum(i) for i in matrix5x5] 
print(sum_row)
```

OUTPUT:

```
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Comment: You could access the elements in the list by indexing

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one:

```
sum_row = [1,1,1,1,1] # example
YourList = [13,13,11,11,9]
result = []                        
for i in range(0, len(sum_row)):
     result.append(sum_row[i]*YourList[i])

print result
```

and the output going to be:

```
[13, 13, 11, 11, 9]
```

You can even try with `[5,5,5,5,5]` as the sum of each row.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip()` function:

```
result = [a * b for a, b in zip(sum_row, [13,13,11,11,9])]
print(result)

# OUTPUT
# [65, 65, 55, 55, 45]
```

Comment: how I would I get it to print [65, 65, 55, 55, 45]

Answer (score 0):

For vectorized calculations, use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
result = np.array(sum_row) * np.array([13,13,11,11,9])
```

result:

```
>>> result
array([65, 65, 55, 55, 45])
```

Comment: When I type print(array) it says 'array' not defined

Comment: You need to assign that line to a `result` and print that.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]

a = l[0] * 13
b = l[1] * 13
c = l[2] * 11
d = l[3] * 11
e = l[4] * 9

print(a, b, c, d, e)
```

Your results will be `13 26 33 44 45`.

Other users have provided much shorter and better ways of doing this, but you should try to understand what they did if you want to follow theirs.